USB Devices not working after enabling VM-Plattform
i´m using podman with wsl. For podman to work the windows feature "VM-Plattform" needs to be active. If that´s the case podman works fine. But while "VM-Plattform" is active none of my USB Devices work. The device manager also list them as broken. If i disable this feature all devices work just fine. I´m using a HP Fury 16 G11 with a thunderbolt Dockerstation, i tried the ports on the laptop aswell as the ports from the dockingstation. They behave the same.
After a boot with the feature active i´m also seeing some usb releated driver errors. The newest HP driver are already installed. Any ideas?






exact same problem here with HP Elitebook 860 G11, W10 Enterprise 22H2 + HP Essential Dock G5
I'm running out of ideas right now..
Edit:
..looks like Comulative Update KB5046613 solves the issue.

This looks more like a comment not an answer for Stackoverflow.
